# How to perform array initialization

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I am trying to check array index element exists or not. It's not working as expected. I am posting the code along with expected output and all the details.

PostgreSQL code:

```
do $$
begin 
   CREATE DOMAIN vararraytype AS numeric(9)[];
END$$;

do $$
begin
create type custschema.coldata_r as (sno numeric, cname varchar, dids integer, dloc varchar2);
END $$;

do $$
begin
create domain custschema.coldata as coldata_r[];
END $$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custschema.upds_func(
p_indarray vararraytype)
RETURNS void AS
$body$
    declare
        v_col_array      custschema.colrectab;
        v_columnRec        custschema.colrec;
        rec record;
        clmdata custschema.coldata; 
begin
for rec in (select sno,cname,dids,dloc from customer where custid='CUST12')
                  loop
                    clmdata[rec.sno]:=rec;
                    raise info ' clmdata[rec.sno] %',clmdata[rec.sno];
                  end loop;
raise info 'p_indarray %',array_length(p_indarray,1);
for x IN 1 .. coalesce(array_length(p_indarray,1),0) 
loop
v_columnRec.colIndex := p_indarray[x] + 2;
raise info 'v_columnRec.colIndex %',v_columnRec.colIndex;

perform custschema.arrayindex(v_columnRec.colIndex)

v_col_array[x] := v_columnRec;
end loop;
end $body$ language plpgsql;

**Output of raise info  from "custschema.upds_func" function.**
raise info ' clmdata[rec.sno] %',clmdata[rec.sno];

clmdata[rec.sno] (1,Abi,15,Hyd)
clmdata[rec.sno] (2,Jhon,15,Mum)
clmdata[rec.sno] (3,Thomas,20,Bang)
clmdata[rec.sno] (4,Marry,25,SYD)
clmdata[rec.sno] (5,Tina,7,KCP)
clmdata[rec.sno] (6,Jorge,10,LOL)
clmdata[rec.sno] (7,Michal,15,CHE)
clmdata[rec.sno] (8,Chanu,9,USA)

raise info 'p_indarray %',array_length(p_indarray,1); -- O/P 3
raise info 'v_columnRec.colIndex %',v_columnRec.colIndex; -- O/P 3


create or replace  function custschema.arrayindex(atrindx  IN NUMERIC,cname   out VARCHAR) AS
$body$
declare 
clmdata custschema.coldata;
begin
raise info 'atrindx %',atrindx;
raise info 'sno %',clmdata[attrIndex].sno;
if clmdata[atrindx].sno IS NULL then
raise exception e'%',  'invalid index';
end if;
cname := clmdata[atrindx].col_nme;
end $body$ language plpgsql;

**Output of raise info  from "custschema.arrayindex" function.**
raise info 'atrindx %',atrindx;  --O/P 3
raise info 'sno %',clmdata[attrIndex].sno; -- O/P NULL

Then raising the exception "invalid index".
```

**Oracle code.**

```
procedure arrayindex(atrindx  IN integer,cname   OUT varchar2) 
is
v_sno integer;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('atrindx' ||atrindx);
v_sno:=clmdata(attrIndex).sno;
dbms_output.put_line('v_sno'||v_sno );
if (not clmdata.exists(atrindx)) then  
gnvGen.toStr(attrIndex-2));
raise ind_excetion;
end if;
cname := clmdata(atrindx).col_nme;
end;

dbms_output.put_line('atrindx' ||atrindx); -- O/P 3
dbms_output.put_line('v_sno'||v_sno );
v_sno 3
v_sno 4
v_sno 5
```

In Oracle v_sno:=clmdata(attrIndex).sno; giving data as 3,4,5. Whereas in PostgreSQL  v_sno:=clmdata(attrIndex).sno; giving NULL.

Comment: What is `vararraytype`? What are the arguments you feed the function and the data in the tables?

Comment: do $$
 begin 
    CREATE DOMAIN vararraytype AS numeric(9)[];
 END $$;
 
p_indarray vararraytype;
raise info ' p_indarray %',p_indarray; -- is printing  p_indarray {1,2,3}

Comment: This is unreadable. Please [edit] the question and put the (formatted) information there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the `IF` condition.

This expression:

```
if (not (coalesce(clmdata[atrindx]::text,'') <> '' and coalesce(array_length(clmdata,1),0) < 1)
```

This expression is syntactically wrong, so the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement will fail.

So your actual function must be different.

You should simplify your check to

```
IF clmdata[atrindx] IS NULL THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'invalid index';
END IF;
```

Besides, it may well be that

```
clmdata[atrindx] IS NOT NULL
```

but

```
(clmdata[atrindx]).col_nme IS NULL
```

A composite type `IS NULL` only if all its components are NULL.

General advice: write cleaner, well indented code, then you will have a much better time debugging it.

Comment: Hi,

I have tried  
if clmdata[atrindx].col_nme IS NULL then 
RAISE EXCEPTION 'invalid index';
end if;

It's raising exception.

In arrayindex function the IN paramter atrindx is printing as 3.

When I use clmdata[atrindx] it is giving me NULL.

thanks.

Comment: Right, so your `IF` statement (that must be different from the one in the question, because that causes a syntax error) is wrong.

Comment: Ideally it should not. I need help in initializing clmdata[atrindx] with atrindx  value 3. Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a programming school. A tip (as stated in my answer): indent your code and make it readable.

Comment: Hi , I have edited my post with all the details. Please help me.

Comment: Hi , Any body could please help me.